# Query to be used in the conditions, when space in between the value

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I am using JQuery and CakePHP for my application.  I have a table `Attributes(id,form_id,label,type)`

In this table, I have an entry like

```
1 1 First name Text
2 1 Lastname Text
```

I have written a CakePhp query to retrieve the `id` given the `form_id` and the `label`

```
$attri = $this->Attribute->find('all', array(
   'fields'=> array('Attribute.id'),
   'conditions' => array(
      'Attribute.form_id' => $id,
      'Attribute.label' => $key
   )
));
```

where `$key` is my `label` and `$id` is my `form_id`.
However, since the First name includes the space in between, the conditions didn't work well, but it works for Lastname since it didn't have space in between.
How can I fix this?

Edit:

I am using MySQL database. The user can keep whatever the fieldname. 
I got the parameters $key from a form using $_POST, e.g.:

```
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value): 
echo $key; //displays First name correctly.
```

But when I use $key in the conditions, only if no spaces are in between the label it accepts, it will return the attribute id, else nothing is returned.

I even tried with using "$key", but it doesn't work either.

Comment: why does your column have a space in it? what database are you using? i would suggest putting an underscore between first_name or changing it to firstname

Comment: I don't see any reason why a space in conditions wouldn't work.. Where do you get your parameters from? Are they urlencoded?

Comment: I am using MYSQl database. The user can kept whatever the fieldname.

The parameters $key i got it form a form using $_POST

eg
foreach ($_POST as $key => $value):
echo $key;//displays First name correctly.
But if i used $key in the conditions only if no spaces in between the label it accepts and returning the attribute id.Else nothing is returned..

Comment: Can you turn debug to level 2 and show us the query that's being generated? What type is the 'label' column in your database (varchar, text etc)? What's it do when you run the query by hand on your database?

Comment: SELECT `Attribute`.`id` FROM `attributes` AS `Attribute` WHERE `Attribute`.`form_id` = 1 AND `Attribute`.`label` = 'Dateof_joining'

Comment: `Attribute.label = 'Dateof_joining'`? That doesn't seem like what you expected. Seem like you'll have to check your code where that key came from.

Comment: BTW, as a last resort, you may be able to do something with [`Inflector::humanize($key)`](http://book.cakephp.org/view/572/Class-methods), but you better try to sort your internally passed data out before resorting to these kind of hacks.

Answer (score 0):

The bug must be somewhere else in your code. It is perfectly fine to have spaces in the values that you use for conditions. See [this page in the CakePHP book](http://book.cakephp.org/view/74/Complex-Find-Conditions) for an example. CakePHP automatically escapes the values for you so they work, even with spaces.

Have a look at your Attribute model and see what happens in the beforeFind or afterFind callbacks.